# C++20 concept fails to compile when template class object instantiated with value

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, concept

Please refer to the following C++20 code:

```
template<bool op>
class Person
{
    const bool own_pet;

public:
    Person() : own_pet(op) {}
    consteval bool OwnPet() const { return own_pet; }
    consteval bool OwnPetC() const { return true; }
    void PatPet() const {}
};

template<typename T>
concept MustOwnPet = requires(T obj) {
    requires obj.OwnPet();
};

void pat(const MustOwnPet auto& p)
{
    p.PatPet();
}

template<typename T>
concept MustOwnPetC = requires(T obj) {
    requires obj.OwnPetC();
};

void pat_c(const MustOwnPetC auto& p)
{
    p.PatPet();
}

int main()
{
    // Error in gc 12.1 with -std=c++20:
    //   in 'constexpr' expansion of 'obj.Person<true>::OwnPet()'
    //   <source>:16:24: error: 'obj' is not a constant expression
    // Also doesn't compile in clang 14.0.0 with -std=c++20
    // pat(Person<true>());

    // Error in clang 14.0.0 with -std=c++20
    // Compiles fine in gcc 12.1 with -std=c++20
    pat_c(Person<true>());

    return 0;
}
```

My understanding is that both `Person::OwnPet()` and `Person::OwnPetC()` are compile time functions as `op` is known as compile time as instantiated in `main()`.

Then why the `pat()` fails to compile? Please see error in the code comment.

And `pat_c()` fails to compile only in `clang` but compiles fine in `gcc`. Which compiler is correct?

Comment: Looks like a gcc bug to me. "A local parameter shall only appear as an unevaluated operand within the constraint-expression." In `obj.OwnPetC()` `obj` os not an unevaluated operand,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem** is that the parameter named `obj` is not a *constant expression*. Thus it cannot be used in an evaluated context where a constant expression is required. For example, we cannot use `obj` as a template nontype parameter(TNP) as TNP must be compile time constant which `obj` is not.

> Which compiler is correct?

This seems to be a bug in gcc submitted [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=106313)

Answer (score -1):

Following code works with `GCC 12.1` and `-std=c++20`. I am not that familiar what you are trying to achieve but I guess the problem here is the member variable which is the same for all template instances and should therefore be a `static constexpr`. If that is the case, `OwnPet()` can be evaluated at compile time. In the other case it is logical for us humans that it can also be evaulated at compile time but I guess not for the compiler (because accessing a member variable instead of a const-expression)

```
template<bool op>
class Person
{
    static constexpr bool own_pet = op;

public:
    Person() {}
    consteval bool OwnPet() const { return own_pet; }
    consteval bool OwnPetC() const { return true; }
    void PatPet() const {}
};

template<typename T>
concept MustOwnPet = requires(T obj) {
    requires obj.OwnPet();
};

void pat(const MustOwnPet auto& p)
{
    p.PatPet();
}

template<typename T>
concept MustOwnPetC = requires(T obj) {
    requires obj.OwnPetC();
};

void pat_c(const MustOwnPetC auto& p)
{
    p.PatPet();
}

int main()
{
    pat(Person<true>());
    pat_c(Person<true>());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I also find compiling. I thought I can use `obj` because both `OwnPet()` and `OwnPetC()` are compile time functions.